# Laravel Pass empty or NULL value to database

Tags: php, laravel, api

I'm stuck on some maybe basic knowledge.

I'm trying to save some data coming from an API and everything seems good, until some of these values does not exist.

I got the error

> "Undefined Offset"

This is my code:

```
$client = new Client(['headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json']]); 
        $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://example.com/api/example/get?apiKey=xxxx');
        $data = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(),true);
        $eventos = $data['Data'];
        foreach($eventos as $item)
        {
            DB::table('apidata')->updateOrInsert([
                'matchID'=>$item['matchID']],
                [
                'matchID'=>$item['matchID'],
                'startTime'=>$item['startTime'],
                'fullTime'=>$item['fullTimeScore'],
                'timeLive'=>$item['timeLive'],
                'homeTeam'=>$item['homeTeamInfo']['homeTeam'],
                'homeGoals'=>$item['homeTeamInfo']['homeGoals'],
                'awayGoals'=>$item['awayTeamInfo']['awayGoals'],
                'awayTeam'=>$item['awayTeamInfo']['awayTeam'],
```

For example if "fullTime" is not set in API, it throws me that error. Much appreciated!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: I've tried with isset, but always returns me 1. Also what is the best implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce), `??` like this:

```
'fullTime'=>$item['fullTimeScore'] ?? null,
'timeLive'=>$item['timeLive'] ?? null,
'homeTeam'=>$item['homeTeamInfo']['homeTeam'] ?? null,
'homeGoals'=>$item['homeTeamInfo']['homeGoals'] ?? null,
```